# PyQt5/Python - Multiple keypress events are called with only 1 keypress

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

So I have the following basic window, my issue is that whenever I press the tab button once it triggers the event twice. Printing "tab" and "keypress" twice. I looked around and all I found about this issue was a C++ answer, I tried to understand the solution but was unable too.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets 
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(self)

        # Install the event filter that will be used later to detect key presses
        QtWidgets.qApp.installEventFilter(self)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Test', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)


     def handleButton(self):
         print("Button")

     def eventFilter(self, obj, event):

            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
                print("keypress")
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
                    self.close()
                if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
                    print("Tab")
                    pass
            return super(ItemPrice, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There's no need to use an event-filter for this, since Qt already provides [QShortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html): `QtWidgets.QShortcut('Esc', self, self.close); QtWidgets.QShortcut('Tab', self, lambda: print('Tab'))`.

Comment: swallowing an event can have unwanted side-effects too

Comment: @PRMoureu. Yes. The Tab key is special - `QApplication` gets an event for each widget that can receive the keyboard focus, because it has to manage the tab-chain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eventFilter()` method needs a boolean result, or 0/1, to return if an event is relevant or not (the filter part). When you return `False` the event is not blocked, and will hit his target, this lets the application handle the event in a normal way.

In your example, when an expected key is pressed (this is a relevant event), you need to return `1` or `True` to "intercept" it and prevent the program to handle it, since you provide your own process. In the other cases, you can call the super method like you did :

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
        print("keypress")

        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
            self.close()
            return 1
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:
            print("Tab")
            return 1

    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Comment: @Gorian thanks for the feedback ! pay attention to ekhumoro's comment, in your case it can be more appropriate and also easier to implement